# How to edit Json File array using Python?

Tags: python, json

First of all take a look at my json structure:
**file0.json**

```
[
 {
        "id": "13",
        "alternate_id": "12",
        "count": 1,
  },
  {
     "id": "14",
        "alternate_id": "11",
        "count": 1,
  }
]
```

Now I have new data that needed to updated in same file
so how to update the data in json file with python code without opening manuelly
I'll show you my desired output :
**file0.json**

```
[
 {
        "id": "13",
        "alternate_id": "12",
        "count": 2,
  },
  {
     "id": "14",
        "alternate_id": "11",
        "count": 4,
  }
]
```

Comment: What's the logic behind count updates?

Comment: Look into python’s json module. You can read the json as a Python dictionary, make the modifications, then save that dictionary back to a json file.

Comment: What have you tried? What does the question have to do with `arrays` or `automated-tests`? What part of the problem are you stuck on? Reading the .json file? Modifying a list of dictionaries? Somehow computing the increase in count (which isn't clear from you example)? Writing the updated list back to file? Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

we can you [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) or [json dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to read json file
for example,

```
import json

with open('sample.json', 'r') as openfile:
 
    # Reading from json file
    json_object = json.load(openfile)
print(json_object)
```